# Android Message Sending

Tags: android

Is there any source code to send same messages to multiple recipients.
Here I need to send some message to multiple recipients. I should be able to select phone numbers and send that message.
Can any one please add any sample code with a apt user interface...

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to save the list of selected numbers in an array and perform the sending operation on each number in a loop...
hope this helps.. Cheers:)